# How to install mosquitto

Tags: protocol

What are the steps to getting and installing mosquitto in ubuntu. Although I have read a lot about MQTT, I am very new to this thing, so please provide detailed information.

Comment: Would recommend to have a look at http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/install-mosquitto-linux/
Great info for MQTT beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instructions, and post your question if you have one.

http://mosquitto.org/download/

Instructions taken from the Mosquitto website.

---

**Ubuntu**

As of version 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot, mosquitto will be in the Ubuntu repositories so you can install as with any other package. If you are on an earlier version of Ubuntu or want a more recent version of mosquitto, add the mosquitto-dev PPA to your repositories list – see the link for details. mosquitto can then be installed from your package manager.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

If the command “apt-add-repository” is not recognised, it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then mosquitto can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
```